# A square and a circle at once

Tags: logical-deduction

Can you draw something on a piece of paper that looks like a square and a circle at the same time? ( without using Math or 3-d visualisation techniques)

Comment: How about this one
http://petapixel.com/assets/uploads/2011/08/circles.jpg

Comment: If you use the Chebyshev norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ rather than the Euclidean one, then circles *are* squares.

Comment: First guess: draw a [squircle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle). Second guess: the answer to the question is "no, such a task is impossible"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible answer ( like Marylin Vos Savant said try to find many possible useful answers to one problem ) ;just draw a circle on a piece of paper , it 'looks' like a circle , it also looks like a 'zero' which is a square integer....

Answer (score 11):

You can draw a cylinder, which (a real 3D object, not the 2D drawing) can look like a square and like a circle, depending on how you turn it.[image].

Comment: nice Also you can cut that cylinder into a shape which can give a triangle as the third projection.

Comment: The problem however, is that if you draw it on a piece of paper, you only have the one perspective.

Comment: @TimCouwelier, if you draw an elephant on a post mark, does it become a small animal?

Comment: No, it becomes a small drawing of the animal.

Comment: @TimCouwelier similarly cylinder does not lose other perspectives if you draw only one.

Comment: But you cannot get it to look both square and circular from that perspective alone. A drawing of just a cylinder looks like a cylinder, not like a square and circle.

Comment: @TimCouwelier, yes, and the question does not ask for it. It ask to draw "something that looks like a square and a circle at the same time".

Comment: Yet you can't see the rectangle. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree, and stop derailing the discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an edge-view picture of a square or a circle: |

It looks like both at once, or indeed like any other planar polygon viewed edge-on.  It is fairly easy to draw, using a pencil, ruler, and piece of paper.